# Best workflow for to work with Ionic2 and Angular2

Tags: deployment, ionic-framework, angular, vagrant, phpstorm

I'm usually developing PHP backend apps. I'm developing on Windows and use Vagrant to create virtual machine.

Workflow looks like that:

1. On base machine I have all my project files and I'm using git.
2. On base machine I have installed PhpStorm which is connected over ssh to virtual machine. PhpStorm is syncing files from base machine to local machine (in one direction)* using deployment.
3. Every library and module like nodejs, ruby, gulp etc. I'm installing on virtual machine to not clutter my base machine.
4. Debugging works fine - I can connect PhpStorm debugging over remote ssh.

Almost everything it's fine with that workflow (sometimes I have to download some generated files on virtual machine), but that workflow is not the best for working with Ionic2 and Angular.

Ionic uses many nodejs modules -> this causing many problems in PhpStorm to hinting errors and code completion. Second problem is debuging I can't connect typescript debugging from PhpStorm because all files all generated by gulp on virtual machine.

**My question is:**

- What's is the best workflow when I want to work on windows with ionic2?
- Do I have to install all libraries on Windows machine?
- Should I use shared folders for that project is any possibility to hinting in PhpStorm?

---

- base machine - on Windows
- virtual machine - on Ubuntu 14 Server LTS
- I can't use shared folders cause of slowly cache creating on PHP app and in general PHP apps running then very slowly, even if I moved cache folder to not shared folder on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have Ionic CLI installed you can start new project by *ionic start* command. It provides you workflow with everything you can need. For example:

   `$ ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2 //create new project
   $ cd cutePuppyPics
   $ ionic serve //start server, live reload etc.`
2. Yes, you should install it all on your non-virutal desktop, because if you want to test app on your device, it will be hard to link this device to ADB in your virtual machine.
3. It works very well with PhpStorm :)